# Error check ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables

Tags: path, sdk, ionic4, java-home

To generate apk  run

```
 ionic cordova build android
```

after some process it generate error.

I set user variables

```
ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Zohab Ud Din\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.1

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2

PATH = ...;C:\Users\Zohab Ud Din\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

and I didn't add anything in the system variable

my error is

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 12.0.2
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Zohab Ud Din\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess Cordova.



 cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to `PC properties` -> `Environment Variable` -> `Use variable for Your_User_name`

Add `USED` variable FOR `Your_User_name`-> Add `New`
Variable: `JAVA_HOME`
Value: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221`

Variable: `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`
Value: `C:\Users\Your_User_name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

Add following paths to the environment variable `PATH`:

```
C:\Users\Your_User_name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
C:\Users\Your_User_name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms
C:\Users\Your_User_name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221
C:\Gradle\gradle-6.3\bin
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues, this is the resolution for me.

Please, my configuration is on ionic1 and OSX, so maybe you need to adapt (windows or ubuntu ..)

> *indication to write in you terminal*

```
Result of your terminal
```

### Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 12.0.2

*First check your version of JAVA*

> java -version

*If you had something like this, it's not good*

```
java version "14" 2020-03-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14+36-1461)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14+36-1461, mixed mode, sharing)
```

***Second List your's versions of Java***

> /usr/libexec/java_home -V

*Maybe you have something like this (if you haven't the second Virtual Machine please install it : https://www.java.com/en/download/)*

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    14, x86_64: "Java SE 14"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_144, x86_64:  "Java SE 8"     /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home
```

***Third switch the version of Java***

*Try this solution first by replace "1.8.0_144" by your version*

> /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_144

*If is not working like me, use the second solution to modify bash_profile file (environment variables)*

> open .bash_profile

Add this line (adapt with your java version)

```
# SWITCH TO JAVA VERSION 8
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

> source ~/.bash_profile

***now you should no longer have this error and you can build***

After this modification, if you have this message wit build android,

```
Subproject Path: app
/Users/quentin/Documents/VOLPY/APPS/app-mobile/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code EACCES
```

please try this (you need to be in the project folder)

> sudo chmod 755 platforms/android/gradlew

### ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting) ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Zohab Ud Din\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)

*You need to add this variable environment missing : **ANDROID_SDK_ROOT** (please adapt if you not use osx, looking for "environment variable")*

> open .bash_profile

***copy past lines of *ANDROID_HOME* by replace by *ANDROID_SDK_ROOT* and commented by # ANDROID_HOME lines***

```
# Set Android_HOME
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk/
#export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk/
  
# Add the Android SDK to the ANDROID_HOME variable
#export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
#export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$PATH
```

> source ~/.bash_profile
> set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk/

- Reboot your computer

***now you should have this message like this if you build***

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/quentin/Library/Android/sdk/ (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/quentin/Library/Android/sdk/ (DEPRECATED)
...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

***Now everything is ok for you, i hope :)***

Answer (score 0):

A restart of the windows after installing jdk solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have to uninstall jdk-17xxx/jdk-14xxx/or whatever version you have installed before and open new terminal/bash and build again.

Answer (score -1):

install `JDK 8` its mismatching download it following link

> Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version:
>   12.0.2

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html