# Ionic Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: cordova is not defined

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, java-home

I don't know anything about Ionic, but I was asked to configure the development environment and run an existing ionic angular app.

Can someone please help me to make this work.

*P.S.: The project/app I'm trying to run in my environment is working and is already being used by people. It is an existing project. So probably I'm mistaking something.*

I installed:

- Node.js v14.18.1
- Ionic   v5.4.16

I installed Node.js v14.18.1 becouse in the pipeline of this project was pecified that version:

> ```
>  - task: NodeTool@0
>    displayName: 'switch npm 13.5.0'
>    inputs:
>      versionSpec: '14.18.1'
> ```

At the end when I rund `>ionic serve` I get [this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVWZH.png)

Also when I run `>ionic cordova build android` I get this errors:

> 1. All imports on this line are unused.
> 2. Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
>    [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

When I check java version in CMD: `java --version` I get this:

> openjdk 11.0.12 2021-07-20

> OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-25199 (build 11.0.12+7)

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-25199 (build 11.0.12+7, mixed mode)

but I can't find Java_Home in MY Environment Variabiles.

---

### Update

I folowed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57139168/error-check-android-sdk-root-java-home-path-environment-variables) to set up Java.
Here are my environment variables:
[image]

And here is PATH variables:
[image]

but when I run `ionic cordova build android` i get error:
[image]

in CMD java version is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the world of ionic.

The error `ReferenceError: cordova is not defined` tells you that there is some function that needs cordova to work. That means it will not work in a browser, only on mobile devices.

Regarding
Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable.

You must manually add the JAVA_HOME variable in your system.

1. Check the path where java is installed.
2. Open System Environment Variables.
3. Create the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
4. Restart the computer.

Here is a tutorial on how to fix it:
[tutorial](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/how-to-set-java-home-environment-variable-on-windows-10)